# html formatted email using form api

Tags: forms

I have created my contact us module using form api, email is successfully generated and send to my specified email address, but I need body of the email to b html formatted, for this I have created another file `mymodule.install` in my module folder and add the below code:

```
function mymoduleenable() {
 $current = variable_get('mail_system', array('default-system' =>    'DefaultMailSystem'));
 $addition = array('mymodule' => 'mymoduleMailSystem');
 variable_set('mail_system', array_merge($current, $addition));
}

function mymoduledisable() {
 $mail_system = variable_get('mail_system', array('default-system' => 'DefaultMailSystem'));
 unset($mail_system['mymodule']);
 variable_set('mail_system', $mail_system);
}
```

and in my `mymodule.module`

```
 class mymoduleMailSystem extends DefaultMailSystem {
 public function format(array $message) {
 $message['body'] = implode("\n\n", $message['body']);
 $message['body'] = drupal_wrap_mail($message['body']);
 return $message;
 }
}
```

but due to above all piece of code I am unable to receive email, kindly suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing i do in my module may be it is set to you requirement

```
    global $content;
    $content .= '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Apply</button>';
    $content .= '<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">';
    $content .= '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">';
    $content .= '<div class="modal-content">';
    $content .= drupal_render($form);
    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '</div>';
    return $content;
```

Comment: `$body[] = 'Name: '.$valid_name.'<br />Email: '.$valid_email.'<br />Quantity: '.$valid_quantity.'<br />Article: '.$valid_id.'<br />URL: '.request_uri();` @Adi, I am talking about this line, I need it to be html formatted when email is received